# Using Powershell to export NTFS permissions

Tags: powershell

I am making use of this script to export NTFS permissions from a large folder structure on a file server. I get the information I want to see using `out-gridview`, but I need it in CSV format.

Here is what currently works:

`Get-ChildItem -recurse -force C:\Test -Directory | get-acl | out-gridview`

So I tried the following to get it into CSV format:

`Get-ChildItem -recurse -force C:\Test -Directory | get-acl |export-csv C:\temp\permissions.csv`

However, the output now includes the following in the CSV output:

> Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Test\Subfolder1

How do I exclude the above from the output?

Answer (score 1):

The path must be converted, there is an example of this using ACLs [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/543ee35a-41ce-45ff-a6ac-807da268294f/getacl-access-with-path?forum=ITCG)

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse -force c:\test -Directory | get-acl | %{$_| Add-Member -NotePropertyName Folder -NotePropertyValue (Convert-Path $_.path) -PassThru }|select -ExpandProperty access -property Folder, owner|export-csv C:\temp\permissions.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Fantastic, thanks so much that seems to be working great. Would it have any issue parsing through about 3000 folders?

Comment: Just wondering if you can assist with this, when I run the script some of the folders have long names and are nested within others, so it ends up being over the 256 character limit, and Powershell writes an error for that. Is there anyway to ignore that limit and still include it in the results?

Comment: That is a limit for most cmdlets such as Get-ChildItem. I would recommend checking out https://github.com/alphaleonis/AlphaFS, which uses extends this limit to 32.000 characters.